# Google Drive Java Authentication

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to fetch access token and refresh token using the document specified [here.](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials#retrieve_oauth_20_credentials) While doing so, I am faced with an issue:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory.fromInputStream(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/Class;)
```

Where can I find the jar which contains this class and method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Drive Java client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API) is based on the [Google APIs Java client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list). Make sure you download it as well. The zip contains the library and all its dependencies.

Also make sure that you don't have conflicting versions of the Google Apis Client library in your compile/classpath as this method is only available in later versions.

Comment: I tried after downloading the zip and using all the libraries and its dependencies, but still got the same error. com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory is available in google-http-client-1.8.3-beta.jar, but the error shows that it does not have fromInputStream method....Is there any other jar file which contains this package?

Comment: That could typically happen if you have a conflicting version of a one of the dependencies. For instance you could be using another version of google-http somewhere in your path...
Also you could try to get our Java sample running all the instructions are here: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java

Comment: Because if your compiler does not detect that the .fromInputStream is missing this means that you are compiling with a different version that actually running your Java code with. Are you using other Google APIs in your code? they might be using older google-http-client with deprecated methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help..You were right, there was a conflicting version of one of the dependencies

Comment: Nivco, I tried that example and I was able to get access token and refresh token using the authorization code..however there is no example to get an accesss token using refresh token. i.e., when I dont have an authorization code..Can you provide me the sample program or any link where I can find this??

Comment: I have some code sample to share with you. Can you post a new question about this? It might be of interest to other people. (put the link here) - 

Also don't forget to validate (the green tick-mark) the good answers to your questions. I will help other people identified correct answers quickly and it rewards the person who answered by giving them reputation points.

Comment: I have posted a new question....here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533203/fetching-access-token-from-refresh-token-using-java