# Fetching access token from refresh token using Java

Tags: google-drive-api

I got the refresh token and access token from the authorization code by using the sample program given here https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials#retrieve_oauth_20_credentials

But there is no sample program to get the access token from refresh token i.e., when we dont have  authorization code. Any pointers? Is there any way to Instantiate a drive service object using only refresh token and access token?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [DrEdit Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java#storing_and_retrieving_credentials_from_the_database) sample has an example on how to retrieve stored Credentials from the Google App Engine Datastore.

If using another type of credentials store, you can use the following code to instantiate new OAuth 2.0 Credentials using stored tokens:

```
GoogleCredential credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).build()
    .setRefreshToken("<REFRESH_TOKEN>").setAccessToken("<ACCESS_TOKEN>");
```

EDIT: Corrected a typo in the code.

Comment: This makes me get an invalid_grant response... any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you can't refresh the token, this usually means that the user has revoked access and subsequent refresh will fail.

Comment: in  this example, REFRESH_TOKEN and ACCESS_TOKEN is from Credentials  that was saved in Database?

Comment: I tried a lot for 3 days to create credentials object in other ways. But this one worked fine. Thank you very much @Alain.

Comment: For the record, you don't have to set access token.  You can simply set refresh token, then call credentials.refreshToken() which will get you a new access token.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code. This is a mix solution from Alain + https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authorization. this worked for me.

```
GoogleCredential credential = createCredentialWithRefreshToken(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new TokenResponse().setRefreshToken(refreshToken));

credential.refreshToken(); 

String newAccessToken = credential.getAccessToken();

public static GoogleCredential createCredentialWithRefreshToken(HttpTransport transport, 
        JsonFactory jsonFactory, TokenResponse tokenResponse) {
    return new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(transport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
        .build()
        .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
}
```

Comment: Just edited my earlier code as I was mistakenly giving call to access token instead of refresh token.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain my experience.

Had the same problem (access token to null) the problem was that I had been tested without sending setAccessType ("offline") and from the account access was allowed access.

Then I put on my code setAccessType ("offline") code but still refresh token to null.

My solution was to revoke permission from the account I want to access (https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en). In the next test I grant it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example:

```
private static void getAccessTokenFromRefreshToken() throws IOException {
    GoogleCredential credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY).setTransport(httpTransport).build()
        .setRefreshToken(REFRESH_TOKEN);

    String accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken();
    System.out.println("Access token before: " + accessToken);

    credentials.refreshToken();

    accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken();
    System.out.println("Access token after: " + accessToken);
}
```

Output:

```
Access token before: null
Access token after: ya29.u4HC22-Avc0aaDC0g0zj1jhz2yjsJrm8qm0hU2eVeBrf6DKj3CcHDQ42KARH4y_d364-b
```

Comment: i didnt get any thing such as CLIENT_SECRET. where to find it? I only have CLIENT_ID