# DocuSign asking for credentials while generating oauth token and access token through code

Tags: docusignapi

When I try to create oauth token through API, it asks me to open browser and login first then I receive the oauth token.

Also the session logs me out after few minutes.

Is there a direct way to create **oauth token and access token through python API**? 
I checked the docusign python SDK but didn't find any direct way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry, that's part of oauth, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717194/does-oauth-2-0-always-require-a-browser-in-the-flow for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the JWT flow can be used to obtain an access token without any user interaction, it should **not** be used if the user is present.

Notes about the authorization code grant flow: it includes a `refresh token` which can be used to generate a new access token if the previous access token has expired.

This means that your user only needs to authenticate with DocuSign once. After that the refresh token can be used to generate new access tokens. Some fine print: you'll want to request the `extended` scope, and you'll need to generate a new access token at least once every 30 days.

### Added

Benefits of Authorization Code grant:

- The user can choose to authenticate or not
- If single sign on (SSO), 2 factor authentication or other InfoSec measures are introduced to the authentication process, then your application will automatically support the new measures. This is not true for JWT grant.

  For example, your company installs a SSO system to increase ease of use, better monitor application usage, etc. If your app uses DocuSign Authorization Code grant, then your application will automatically support the new SSO system with no changes. Not true if your app uses JWT grant.

Refresh tokens: Refresh tokens last 30 days. If you request `extended` scope then the refresh token will itself be refreshed (for an additional 30 dayes) each time you use it. Thus, if you create a new access token (using the refresh token) at least once every 30 days, the user will never need to re-authenticate.

JWT grant: use this OAuth flow if no user is present. JWT grant provides slightly less information security because it empowers your application to impersonate a user. If the user is present and available to authenticate, then the extra level of empowerment the JWT grant provides was not needed and should not be used--one of the ideas of information security is to be conservative whenever reasonable to do so.

If there's no need to use JWT grant then don't use it.

The benefit of JWT grant is that no human is needed to complete the grant process.

Comment: So, once the refresh token is expired then I again have to generate a new oAuth token which means it will again require manual intervention.

I intent to make the entire authentication process automated. Can you guide me the steps to be followed to make it fully automated?

Comment: Also, is it advisable to use JWT flow if there is no user present? Can you explain me benefits of JWT over Authorization grant flow process?

Comment: See my expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

With [JWT Authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken) you would only need this once ever per user. That is because the user must consent to the application making API calls on their behalf. 
Once this is out of the way, you can get OAUth tokens using the Python API directly without a user, or a browser.

Here is a small code snippet:

```
    cls.ds_app = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
        client_id=DS_JWT["ds_client_id"],
        user_id=DS_JWT["ds_impersonated_user_id"],
        oauth_host_name=DS_JWT["authorization_server"],
        private_key_bytes=private_key,
        expires_in=3600
```

Comment: I wish to use authentication grant token and not JWT.

Can you guide me how to automate the entire authentication process, especially the browser part?

Comment: JWT does grant a token.
And it's the only method that allows you to get a token without a browser and user logging in.