# I am getting an Error in listing the google drive files using Java: 401 Unauthorised error

Tags: java, eclipse, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am trying to list the files in my Google Drive account using a Java application. I followed the Java QuickStart tutorial in the Google developers page, and i have my client secret file and here is my code:

```
Drive service = DriveQuickstart.getDriveService();
FileList result = service.files().list()
                 .setPageSize(10)
                 .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                 .execute();


List<File> files = result.getFiles();
if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println("No files found.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Files:");
    for (File file : files) {
         System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
```

However, when i run my Java application, I get the following error, which is a 401 Unauthorized.

> [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.luledu.eduMod.AddAssignment$GuiWindow.actionPerformed(AddAssignment.java:241)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.mouseClicked(GuiScreen.java:252)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.client.gui.inventory.GuiContainer.mouseClicked(GuiContainer.java:350)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at com.luledu.eduMod.AddAssignment$GuiWindow.mouseClicked(AddAssignment.java:171)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.handleMouseInput(GuiScreen.java:344)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.handleInput(GuiScreen.java:313)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runTick(Minecraft.java:1731)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1039)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:962)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:164)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source)
>   [14:12:01] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:748]:     at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source)
>   `
>   I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this.
>   Best,

Comment: The access token expires after a while, you'll have to get a new one using the refresh token.

Comment: How do we refresh it? I am sorry but I don't have much experience with this API, therefore I do not know much..

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10537925/1552587

Comment: I think there is something wrong with getDriveService() your not authenticated. assuming you have authenticated it once the client library should be getting you a new access token when needed