# Instantiate new OAuth 2.0 Credentials using stored tokens from another way

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm working with Google Calendar API Java on Server side.
I have a token & refresh token from client side and store it into database.

So How I can instantiate new OAuth 2.0 Credentials using these stored tokens for calling Google Calendar Java API?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried by follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533203/fetching-access-token-from-refresh-token-using-java . It worked, but Java Google API throw "Token has been revolked" a few times even if the google account is authenticated a few minutes before

Answer (score 0):

It's stated in [Detecting an expired access token](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2#detecting_an_expired_access_token) that once a token is detected to be no longer valid (ie. expired or revoked), you must remove the access token from your storage.

Likewise, it is also stated in [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6) under Refreshing an Access Token that:

> The authorization server MAY issue a new refresh token, in which case the client MUST discard the old refresh token and replace it with the new refresh token.  The authorization server MAY revoke the old refresh token after issuing a new refresh token to the client.  If a new refresh token is issued, the refresh token scope MUST be identical to that of the refresh token included by the client in the request.